# addEventListener execute code after "if" but doesn't execute code after "else" (onclick display)

Tags: javascript, onclick

Can anybody explain to me why when a code works normally, but the second I use addEventListener it won't read the "display none" function after

```
} else
```

I know there is a lot of codes and questions out there, where people ask about the onclick function. But I haven't found any on why I have to rewrite the code just because I use addEventListener.

So here it will open the menu but it won't close it again but if I remove the addEventListener it will.

```
document.getElementById("menu-item-11109").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('closemenu');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<li onclick="myFunction()" id="menu-item-11109">
<a>Opskrifter</a>
<ul id="closemenu">
<li>
<a href="https://kvalitet-extensions.dk/category/mad/">Mad og drikke</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide functional example that people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks!

Comment: can you close it again? because I can't but after removing the () as Daniel said it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li onclick="myFunction()" id="menu-item-11109">
```

You should pass a reference to your function that should happen onclick. but instead you are calling myfunction directly.

Solution:

```
<li onclick="myFunction" id="menu-item-11109">
```

Here I am passing a reference to myFunction to the onclick event.